# Document on click using selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

How to get the containing item using document on click.

```
var this_main = $(this);
     $(document).this_main.on('click', '.nav-circlepop a.prev', function(){
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please share the html?

Comment: Please specify more on that, provide full script and describe what you really want to do ? So that we can help you.

Comment: Can you not do just `this_main.on('click'...`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know that what you want to do, but it's for just idea for you

```
$('.nav-circlepop a.prev').click(function(){
     alert("now you can everything with this function");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these one. 
The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object

```
 $(this_main).on('click', '.nav-circlepop a.prev', function () {
    });
```

Comment: Close but this doesn't fire it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're just using excessive code:

```
$('.nav-circlepop a.prev').click(function(){
  console.log('worked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**text**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to grab the text .

Since you have not provided any HTML I presume the below HTML snippet is close to your code

**HTML**

```
<div class = "nav-circlepop">
<a class = "prev" href=""> Anchor tag text </a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-circlepop a.prev', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     document.write('<pre>'+$(this).text()+'</pre>')
});
```

**Code Explanation**

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-circlepop a.prev',function(event){})
```

Any click event on document will be delegate to the target element.

Here the second parameter represent the target element.

where `.nav-circlepop` is a parent element and anchor tag `a` is child element. This anchor tag `a` has a class `prev` .So the target element is `a.prev`

Check this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/f0Ldzqe0/)